# when select is hide the value always have default value

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="seeds-a1" value="Indigofera" /> <span>Indigofera</span>

//this select will show if checkbox mark as checked 

<select class="selectDrop" name="orders">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option>1/2 kg</option>
  <option>1 kg</option>
  <option>2 kg</option>
  <option>3 kg</option>
  <option>4 kg</option>
  <option>5 kg</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="seeds-a2" value="calliandra" /> <span>calliandra</span>

    //this select will show if checkbox mark as checked 

    <select class="selectDrop" name="orders2">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option>1/2 kg</option>
      <option>1 kg</option>
      <option>2 kg</option>
      <option>3 kg</option>
      <option>4 kg</option>
      <option>5 kg</option>
    </select>

   <input type="checkbox" name="seeds-a3" value="ipil-ipil" /> <span>ipil-ipil</span>

    //this select will show if checkbox mark as checked 

    <select class="selectDrop" name="orders3">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option>1/2 kg</option>
      <option>1 kg</option>
      <option>2 kg</option>
      <option>3 kg</option>
      <option>4 kg</option>
      <option>5 kg</option>
    </select>
```

using this **js** select will hide and show my problem is: *is this posible when select is hide always have a default value?*

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name^="seeds-"]').change(function(){
  $(this).nextAll('select.selectDrop').first().toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Thank's  [Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy) this js

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LfS2u/1/)**

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you saying that you would like to reset the `select` element back to its' default value in that event handler?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan OP wants to set the value of the select element to the default one while we hide hide it..!

Comment: yes... that what i want because if you select some value then uncheck the checkbox the the selected value will send to email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('[type="checkbox"][name^="seeds-"]').change(function(){
 var selectElem = $(this).nextAll('select.selectDrop').first();
 selectElem.toggle(this.checked);
 if(!this.checked){ selectElem.val(""); }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LfS2u/2/)

Comment: Thank you Again for you help, I need to wait few minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @jhunlio Glad to help you again..! :)